# Show date difference as "20" instead of "20 years ago"

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

```
{{Carbon::parse($etudiant->date_naissance)->diffForHumans()}}
```

It appears like "20 years ago".
But I want the age to appear only "20"

Answer (score 3):

Use `->diffInYears()`

```
{{Carbon::parse($etudiant->date_naissance)->diffInYears()}}
```

For more informations, check the doc for the *Difference* section [here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference)